# What is the name of this fat-stemmed plant?

Tags: identification, indoors

I got this plant few months back, but I forgot to ask its name from the vendor. Could anyone identify it? I have taken a few pics:

Full Plant:
[image]

Stem:
[image]

Flower:
[image]

Leaves:
[image]

Comment: Upon further examination of the flowering structure and the trunk with the swollen base I don't think it is ficus carica. I'll keep looking...

Comment: @kevinsky the leaves look very ficus... But the flowers look wrong to me.

Comment: I think it may be in Araliaceae

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Jatropha podagrica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jatropha_podagrica) is a very poisonous plant so don't eat any of it. It's an indoor plant and can't survive under 50°F. Water it when dry, give it bright light but avoid direct sun. Other than that it should stay alive for some time.

The plant is an indoor tropical forest type plant and is only poisonous if eaten; if handled just wash your hands thoroughly! But that goes with all poisonous plants although this one is particularly lethal. I think nearly all the species of this plant are bad news.  I learned this one about ten years ago when reading up about survival techniques in the rain forests. I've read that

> "the seeds are violently purgative! it can cause inflammation of the intestines along with diarrhea and vomiting- these conditions can lead to dehydration and could endanger you life in a survival condition, if unable to find prompt medical help"

as quoted from Hugh McManners and one of his many books.

On the other hand it is quite a pretty plant. I would just treat it with respect, etc.

Comment: Poisonous, Oh God!!! Thanks for identifying it. Is it fine to keep this plant indoor? I don't have any pets or children around.